# HALog - Connect and response times percentiles

Tags: haproxy

When I run the following command to parse haproxy logs, the output doesn't contain any headers, and I'm not able to understand the meanings of the numbers in each of the columns.

**Command** `halog -pct < haproxy.log > percentiles.txt`

the output that I see is:

```
0.1 3493 18 0 0 0 
0.2 6986 25 0 0 0 
0.3 10479 30 0 0 0 
0.4 13972 33 0 0 0 
0.5 17465 37 0 0 0 
0.6 20958 40 0 0 0 
0.7 24451 43 0 0 0 
0.8 27944 46 0 0 0 
0.9 31438 48 0 0 0 
1.0 34931 49 0 0 0 
1.1 38424 50 0 0 0 
1.2 41917 51 0 0 0 
1.3 45410 52 0 0 0 
1.4 48903 53 0 0 0 
1.5 52396 55 0 0 0 
1.6 55889 56 0 0 0 
1.7 59383 57 0 0 0 
1.8 62876 58 0 0 0 
1.9 66369 60 0 0 0 
2.0 69862 61 0 0 0 
3.0 104793 74 0 0 0 
4.0 139724 80 0 1 0 
5.0 174656 89 0 1 0 
6.0 209587 94 0 1 0 
7.0 244518 100 0 1 0 
8.0 279449 106 0 1 0 
9.0 314380 112 0 1 0 
10.0 349312 118 0 1 0 
15.0 523968 144 0 1 0 
20.0 698624 168 0 1 0 
25.0 873280 180 0 2 0 
30.0 1047936 190 0 2 0 
35.0 1222592 200 0 3 0 
40.0 1397248 210 0 3 0 
45.0 1571904 220 0 4 0 
50.0 1746560 230 0 6 0 
55.0 1921216 241 0 7 0 
60.0 2095872 258 0 9 0 
65.0 2270528 279 0 10 0 
70.0 2445184 309 0 16 0 
75.0 2619840 354 1 18 0 
80.0 2794496 425 1 20 0 
85.0 2969152 545 1 22 0 
90.0 3143808 761 1 39 1 
91.0 3178740 821 1 80 1 
92.0 3213671 921 1 217 1 
93.0 3248602 1026 1 457 1 
94.0 3283533 1190 1 683 1 
95.0 3318464 1408 1 889 1 
96.0 3353396 1721 1 1107 1 
97.0 3388327 2181 1 1328 1 
98.0 3423258 2902 1 1555 1 
98.1 3426751 3000 1 1580 1 
98.2 3430244 3094 1 1607 1 
98.3 3433737 3196 1 1635 1 
98.4 3437231 3301 1 1666 1 
98.5 3440724 3420 1 1697 1 
98.6 3444217 3550 1 1731 1 
98.7 3447710 3690 1 1770 1 
98.8 3451203 3848 1 1815 1 
98.9 3454696 4030 1 1864 1 
99.0 3458189 4249 1 1923 2 
99.1 3461682 4490 1 1993 2 
99.2 3465176 4766 2 2089 2 
99.3 3468669 5085 2 2195 2 
99.4 3472162 5441 3 2317 97 
99.5 3475655 5899 5 2440 365 
99.6 3479148 6517 11 2567 817 
99.7 3482641 7403 14 2719 1555 
99.8 3486134 8785 16 2992 2779 
99.9 3489627 11650 997 3421 4931 
100.0 3493121 85004 4008 20914 71716
```

The first column looks to be the percentile, (like P50, P90, P99, etc) but the what are the values in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns? Also, are they total values (halog reports total times when provided with other options), or average values or maximum values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<percentile> <request count> <Request Time*> <Connect Time**> <Response Time***> <Data Time****>`

- * [Referred to as TR in the documentation.](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.4)
- ** [Referred to as Tc in the documentation.](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.4)
- *** [Referred to as Tr in the documentation.](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.4)
- **** [Referred to as Td in the documentation.](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.4)

[The source provides some good pointers.](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/26ac8a6c4ed47dbf5d773d59ef09880eaabec8ab/contrib/halog/halog.c#L1145-L1149)

Comment: It's surprising that the same percentile stats can include both the time to receive the request (TR) and time to wait for the response (Tr), which should be independent variables. The doc (linked in the answer) seems to hint that the Tr time includes some time to send the request content to the server and should not be trusted, but that is nevertheless quite difficult to understand.
In my experience, looking only at the Tr time does match the percentiles I get when I extract the response time from the web server itself (nginx behind haproxy), so looking only at Tr seems to make sense.